# QML MouseArea: как передавать события мыши нижележащим MouseArea?

Tags: qt, qt5, qml, qtquick

Есть сложный диалог, с кучей элементов, расположенных внутри сложной иерархии лэйатутов. Мне нужно поверх этого диалога рисовать вертикальную линию-маркер курсора. Линия должна рисоваться поверх всех элементов в диалоге и её координата X должна совпадать с координатой X курсора мыши. То есть линия должна следовать за курсором мыши.
Никак не могу понять как этом можно реализовать. Упрощённый пример кода:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 50
        text: "Button"
        highlighted:  hovered
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: cursorMarker
        width: 1
        color: "black"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: {
            cursorMarker.x = mouse.x
        }

    }
}
```

Здесь, MouseArea управляющий маркером курсора расположен поверх кнопки. Маркер работает как надо, но кнопка совсем не работает - не подсвечивается когда наводим мышь на неё.
Если расположить MouseArea под кнопкой, то кнопка будет работать, но маркер курсора не будет корректно позиционироваться, когда курсор находится над кнопкой. А нужно чтобы работало и то и то.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно разрешить это противоречие? Может быть есть возможность ловить одно и тоже событие в нескольких MouseArea? Или может быть можно как-то пробрасывать события из MouseArea ниже?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop

Comment: Это касается только composed mouse events: clicked, doubleClicked and pressAndHold. А как передавать hover, enter, exit, pressed, released, wheel?

Comment: Оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135262/how-to-include-child-mouse-hover-events-in-the-parent-mousearea-using-qml

Comment: Нет, не оно. Там речь идёт про события entered и exited. А мне нужно событие positionChanged.

Answer (score 0):

как идея: onEntered на кнопку - меняем ей Z (повышаем/понижаем), а на onExited меняем Z обратно...